# Change button text programmatically in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

Here is my code so far:

```js
dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};

resetStopwatch();

require(["dojo/query", "dijit/form/ToggleButton", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query, ToggleButton, Button, dom, domAttr){
  //query("#resume").style("display", "none");

  var timeUpdate, flag; 
  flag = false;

  new ToggleButton({
    showLabel: true,
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(val) {
      if (val) {
        this.set('label', 'Stop');

        var milliseconds = seconds = minutes = hours = 0;

        if(flag){
          // fetch current time in the stopwatch
          milliseconds = parseInt(domAttr.get("milliseconds", "innerHTML"));
          seconds      = parseInt(domAttr.get("seconds", "innerHTML"));
          minutes      = parseInt(domAttr.get("minutes", "innerHTML"));
          hours        = parseInt(domAttr.get("hours", "innerHTML"));
        }

        var startTime = new Date();
        timeUpdate = setInterval(function(){
          var timeElapsed = new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime();

          // calculate hours                
          hours = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000/60/60);
          hours = prependZero(hours);
          domAttr.set("hours", "innerHTML", hours + " h ");

          // calculate minutes
          minutes = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000/60);
          if(minutes > 60)
            minutes = minutes % 60;
          minutes = prependZero(minutes);
          domAttr.set("minutes", "innerHTML", minutes + " m ");

          // calculate seconds
          seconds = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000);
          if(seconds > 60)
            seconds = seconds % 60;
          seconds = prependZero(seconds);
          domAttr.set("seconds", "innerHTML", seconds + " s ");

          // calculate milliseconds 
          milliseconds = timeElapsed;
          milliseconds = prependZero(milliseconds);
          if(milliseconds > 1000)
            milliseconds = milliseconds % 1000;
          if(milliseconds < 10)
            milliseconds = "00" + milliseconds.toString();
          else if(milliseconds < 100)
            milliseconds = "0" + milliseconds.toString();                
          domAttr.set("milliseconds", "innerHTML", milliseconds + " milli");

        },25);  // updated time after every 25ms

      } else {
        this.set('label', 'Resume');
        clearInterval(timeUpdate);
      }
    },
    label: "Start"
  }, "start_stop");

  /*var resumeButton = new Button({
        label: "Resume",
        onClick: function(){
            //clearInterval(timeUpdate);
            //resetStopwatch();        
        }
    }, "resume");  */  

  var resetButton = new Button({
    label: "Reset",
    onClick: function(){
      domAttr.set("start", 'label', "Start");
      clearInterval(timeUpdate);
      resetStopwatch();        
    }
  }, "reset");
});

function resetStopwatch(){
  require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
    domAttr.set("hours",        "innerHTML", "00 h ");
    domAttr.set("minutes",      "innerHTML", "00 m ");
    domAttr.set("seconds",      "innerHTML", "00 s ");
    domAttr.set("milliseconds", "innerHTML", "000 milli");
  });
}

function prependZero(time){
  if(time < 10){
    time = "0" + time.toString();
    return time;
  }
  else
    return time;
}
```

```css
#stopwatch, #buttons{
  text-align: center;
}

.claro *
{
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<div id="stopwatch">
  <span id="hours"></span>
  <span id="minutes"></span>
  <span id="seconds"></span>
  <span id="milliseconds"></span>
</div>
<div id="buttons" class="claro">
  <button id="start_stop"></button>
  <!--<button id="resume"></button>-->
  <button id="reset"></button>
</div>
```

Consider this use-case: click `Start` > after some time, click `Reset` - I plan to change the label from `Stop` to `Start` back again. So, I did:

```
domAttr.set("start", 'label', "Start");   // line # 83
```

But it is throwing an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation states](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/dom-attr.html), you should pass a domNode into domAttr.set, not a string.
So, instead of passing a string, "start", pass in a domNode (by using a data-dojo-attach-point for example).

I think you should replace it with "this.set('label', 'Start');".

This fixes your problem:

```
var startButton = new ToggleButton({
    showLabel: true,
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(val) {
       // code
    },
    label: "Start"
}, "start_stop");

var resetButton = new Button({
    label: "Reset",
    onClick: function(){
        startButton.set('label', "Start");
        clearInterval(timeUpdate);
        resetStopwatch();        
    }
}, "reset");
```

});

Notice that i saved the reference to the startButton, so it can be references in the onClick from the resetButton.

Comment: I didnt quite get you. I am passing `domNode` into `domAttr.set()` as `"start"`. By the way, I cannot do `this.set('label', 'Start');` as it will replace the label of `reset` button with `Start`.

Answer (score 4):

In Dojo there is a difference between widgets and DOM nodes. Your start button is a widget, so setting the label of that widget using a DOM node will not work. To change the label of the widget, you first need to retrieve the widget instance using the `dijit/registry` module or by having a reference to your widget (`ToggleButton`) already.

After that you can use the appropriate [setter](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/ToggleButton#1_9dijit_form_ToggleButton_set) to change the label of the widget.

In your case the best thing to do is create a local reference to the new `ToggleButton`, for example:

```
var startBtn = new ToggleButton({
    /** Your code */
});
```

And then do the following:

```
startBtn.set("label", "Start");
```

As usual, I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/P7b9S/51/).

---

If you would like to use the `dijit/registry` module (which isn't necessary now), you can get a reference to your widget using the widget ID (or the DOM ID) by using:

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
    registry.byId("start_stop").set("label", "Start");
});
```

However, in this case it isn't useful, because you have an easier way of referencing your widget, but keep it in mind for future references (or if you start using declarative widgets).